# Returned object's Id is ZERO ( creating a record in database )

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sails.js, waterline

When I tried to print out the User using `console.log(user);` I discovered that the id was zero. However, in the database(mysql), the user id is showing the correct value, which is the uuid.

Following is my User model

```
module.exports = {

  tableName : 'user',
  autoPK : false,
  attributes: {

  id: {
      type : 'string',
      unique : true,
      primaryKey : true,
      uuidv4 : true,
      columnName: 'id',
      defaultsTo : uuid.v4()
  },

  // { ..... other fields} 
}
```

Following is my create function :

```
 User.create(userObj).done(function(err, user){
  console.log(user);   
.... // other codes
 }
```

Comment: What version of Sails / sails-mysql are you running?

Comment: I am using Sails v0.10.0-rc4 and sails-mysql 0.10.0-rc2.

Comment: Checking this out...in the meantime, you want `defaultsTo: uuid.v4`, not `defaultsTo: uuid.v4()`...unless you want the same UUID for every instance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, it looks like you uncovered a bug in the latest beta version of `sails-mysql`.  It has now been [fixed and published](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-mysql/commit/45a32e152567e32f6b8bb3463c2958d1fea5ff7c), so if you delete your `node_modules/sails-mysql` folder and `npm install sails-mysql@beta` you should be all set.  Thanks!